# Cakephp use numeric values with quote as string is not working

Tags: sql, cakephp, model

I want generate following query.

```
SELECT `Scale`.`id`, `Scale`.`name` 
FROM `woa`.`scales` AS `Scale` 
WHERE `Scale`.`enabled` = '1'
```

So i wrote following lines in cackphp controller.

```
$this->set('scales', $this->Scale->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array('Scale.enabled' => '1')
)));
```

But it generate following query with out quotation in Scale`.`enabled value.

```
SELECT `Scale`.`id`, `Scale`.`name` 
FROM `woa`.`scales` AS `Scale` 
WHERE `Scale`.`enabled` = 1
```

How can i use quotations with numeric (bt actually it is string) value?

Comment: what's wrong with the executed sql? What _error_ does it trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CakePHP handles the quotes according to the actual column datatype. But if you really want to force quotes try this:

```
$this->set('scales', $this->Scale->find('list', array(
    'conditions' => array("Scale.enabled='1'")
)));
```